# DTMF transceiver MT8889CE - trying to make dtmf dialler

Tags: avr

Hi
I'm trying to interface this transceiver chip with my avr. I understand the databits should be connected to my avr. However am unsure of what to do with the rest of the pins. Also how would you get the chip to dial a number.

Answer (score 4):

The datasheet doesn't give a timing diagram for writing to the MT8889, but it contains a number of connection diagrams for different processors, like this one:

[image]

I would consult write timing diagram in the microprocessor's datasheet to see how the different signals relate.

Comment: He's using an AVR so he only needs a single output to drive the CS pin.

Answer (score 2):

I'd forget about that chip and implement DTMF transmission in software. [Here](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc1982.pdf) is an Atmel app. note describing DTMF generation. It's cheaper than using an external chip, and the frequencies may be fine-tuned if necessary. Given the complexity of the MT8889CE interface, using the Atmel software will save a lot of time.

Comment: you don't explain why the software solution would be better. Also, the Atmel appnote only describes a generator, while the MT8889 is a generator/decoder.

Comment: He only wants a dialler!

Comment: Okay, but why is the software solution better?

Comment: I added it to my answer, although it's quite obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the circuit below. I have this IC connected to ATMega162.

[image]